# As I can export the GridControl2 GridControl1 and united?

Tags: c#-4.0, gridview, grid, devexpress

I have `GridControl1` and `GridControl2`, and I can export each Grid to. XLS (Excel) separately.
can I export the `GridControl2` `GridControl1` united??

This is what I have done so far but I can not export them unless I do it separately:

```
grid1.ExportToXls (argumentss);
grid2.ExportToXls (argumentss);
```

Comment: what is the question??? your statements does not express any question  and description about the problem. elaborate more and with correct use of english grammer.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called `CompositeLink`.

Have a look at this Devex article. It has an example.

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A2730.aspx